# Взаимодействия между ViewModel-ями

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Как лучше организовать взаимодействие между ViewModel-ями?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Многое зависит от вида связи моделей вида (родитель-потомок или брат-брат). В общем случае часто используют шину сообщений. Модели подписываются на сообщения определенного типа и получают их, когда другие модели посылают их. Хороший пример реализации - это класс Messenger в 
[MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/).